# How can I keep footnotes together with message text when top-posting?

Tags: emacs, email-client, footnotes, gnus

I want better control of the footnote positioning within an email message. I could write the code to modify `footnote-mode` to do what I want, but first I want to see if somebody else has already solved this problem.

When I am top-posting with `message-mode` and add an entry with `footnote-mode` the footnotes go to the end of the buffer, but instead I want it to come *before* the previous message citation which starts out with something like:

```
Elvis Presley <the.king@graceland.com> writes:
```

If I have a signature automatically added based on `footnote-signature-separator` then the footnotes get positioned before the signature, however in email I don't use a signature. And furthermore, when I use a closing like:

```
-Elvis
```

or

```
Thanks,
 Elvis
```

then I usually want to footnotes to come *after* that closing.

What I would like is to have the best optimal position detected automatically whether I am top-posting or in-line posting. I expect the best solution will be to use `text-properties-at` to detect `gnus-cite-*` lines and maybe to define text properties for the footnotes section. And/or maybe overlays?

Also note that suggestions like the following will **not** work:

```
(setq footnote-signature-separator "^-- $\\|@.*writes:")
```

Not only is that overly simplistic for the kind of positioning control I would like, but it also simply does not work correctly.

Comment: Top-posting is bad and you should feel bad. ;)